# find a substring in a collections.deque

Tags: python

I am trying to search for a substring in a deque collection.

I created a deque construct from collections

Is there a way to find 'this'  within the deque x?

I tried `find('this') in x` but it didn't work.

```
from collections import deque

x = deque('a', 'b', 'c')

'b' in x
```

Output: `True`.

```
x = deque('a', '# this #', 'c')

'this' in x
```

Output: `False`.

Would like a method to find 'this'

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have search for the substring while iterating through the deque:

```
def find(substring, deque):
    for s in deque:
        if substring in s:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Won't the code as-is return after only checking the first entry in the queue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to test each item in the collection.  You could do this in a for-loop:

```
x = deque('a', '# this #', 'c')
def find(collection):
    for item in collection:
        if 'this' in item:
            return True
    return False
```

Or by using the [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) builtin, and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
any('this' in item for item in x)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# regex approach
import re
from collections import deque

x = deque(['a', '# this #', 'c'])
substring= "this"

if re.search(substring, "".join(x)):
    print(True)
```